# GNU Assembly Language

Tags: linux, gnu-assembler

Im trying to work on an assembly homework, but it seems that the cmp part is not working properly, it is not jumping to terminate even if my input is 6, can anyone help?

```
menu:
    call display_menu
    movl  $3, %eax
    movl  $0, %ebx
    movl  $choice, %ecx
    movl  $2, %edx
    int   $0x80


##JE not working 
    cmp $6,(choice)
    je _terminate
    jmp menu

_terminate:
   movl  $1, %eax
   movl  $0, %ebx
   int   $0x80
```

Comment: So then what *is* the value it has?

Comment: i tried storing 6 to choice, and i expected it to jump to terminate part but it didn't?

Comment: You're certain that it's 6 and not 0x36?

Comment: mov 0x36,%al
cmp %al,(choice)
je _terminate

I tried this update but it returned segmentation fault

Comment: i solved it! i used $0x36 instead, i'm totally new in gnu assembly, did not know that scanned values are in hex. Thanks!